# C# Pagination issue

Tags: c#, rest, pagination

I am using C# REST to query USERS object, there are potential 100,000 users or more. also possible 500 users or less, the total quantity users are dynamic, depends on the queried customer by customer.

customer1 could have 90,000 users

customer2 could have 20,000 users

customer3 could have 9000 users

customer4 could have 300 users
etc

the max returned users are 1000.

the query link is https://myserver.com/v1/people?max=1000

if the customer has more than 1000 users, then the response header will contain the pagination link, we can use the new link to query next 1000 users, the new link like

https://myserver.com/v1/people?max=1000&cursor=kl23iIS823gzkwoi20

if the new query response header contains a new link, that means still more users. the new new link like

https://myserver.com/v1/people?max=1000&cursor=Gi233iIS8ag;2zkwo42

hope I explained clearly here.

as you can see, the total users is unknown, if there are multiple pages of 1000 users, we need query a new link everytime, we don't know the new new link unless we did previous new link query, and we don't know how many times to complete all queries, and each next query link is depends on the previous query, nested.

what is the best way to address the query using C#?

thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at the [tag:paging] tag: "A memory-management technique where a computer stores and retrieves data from secondary storage for use in main memory. Memory is divided into equal sized pages so to not waste any memory."  Are you sure this is the correct tag for your question?  Also, you didn't tag the question with C#.  And based on your question, I am wondering if there is a database involved that should be tagged as well.  Proper tags will help drive people with knowledge of those tags to your question to help you find an answer.

Comment: thanks Alex, trying to edit my post

Comment: Why not just send the total number of users as well? In fact, I wouldn't send a link for the next page at all. I'd just send the total number of users and which page of users is being returned. From that, the client should be able to handle everything from showing the total number of pages to going to a particular page to making previous and next links and even first and last page links.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

the server only can return up to 1000 lines of user per request, so even I want to list all 100,000 users once, the server only return 1000

when server response the request, in the response header, it will give a new link to tell there are more users

Comment: Are you in control of the API reponse? I wasn't advising to make it return more than 1000 lines per request. I was saying how I would change the API response to include the information needed for the client to handle pagination more gracefully.

Comment: thanks again for reply

Yes, I am in control of the API response, after I sent API request, I can receive API response.

my API request 1000 lines data to return.

if there are more than 1000 lines, the response header will contain a link like below.

https://myserver.com/v1/people?max=1000&cursor=bGltaXQ9NSZydEluZGV4PTY

I will need send API request (1000 lines of data) again with the link above.

if still more users, then a new link generated, i need query the new link again.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are in control of your API response, you can make your API response to return the total number of users based on the query
e.g.

```
{
    "users": [...
         /// user data
     ],
    "paging":
     {
       "pageNo": 5,
       "pageSize": 50,
       "pageCount": 5,
       "totalRecordCount": 220,
    }
}
```

if you cannot change the response format, you can also send the total number of records as part of response header.

Client can then derive the pagination logic based on the pagination values. You need not have to return the next page link. The request in that case should have the offset or page number parameter for you to identify which set of data to return as part of response
e.g https://myserver.com/v1/people?max=1000&pageno=5&pagesize=50

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood "in control of API response", 

I don't have control of the API response, so I can't produce paging info or total users info,

Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I figured out

use a "do while" loop

if more users, continue loop till no more users.